# how to sensitize req.body object data in express

Tags: api, express, request

I want to remove all malicious data input from my express api requests?
how I sensitize data

```
"use strict";
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser =  require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
var util= require('util');
var cors = require('cors');
```

I am using this all package in above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer to sanitize npm package for your request object
Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) to do that sanitize process, in the following way.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
function sanitize(body, values) {
  return _.pick(req.body, values);
}
console.log(sanitize(req.body, ['name', 'email', 'password']));
```

If you are using express you can the following middleware as follow:

```
const validatorFunc = (values) => {
  return (req,res,next) => {
    const data = _.pick(req.body, values);
    req.body = data;
    next();
  }
}
```